Schema query changes execution time with larger number of tables
The execution time changes from 7 ms --> 1254 ms.
Postgres 16.3 on Ubuntu 24.04
The following SQL query which runs from an open source library I'm using finds the foreign key constraints within a schema/table.  However the PG optimiser changes the way it optimises the query based upon the number of tables in the SCHEMA.  Does anyone know if there is a way to force the use of the faster optimisation method? This query can be run on any recent version of Postgres.
SELECT tc.constraint_name, kcu.column_name, ccu.table_name, ccu.column_name, 0
FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc
         JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
              ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
         JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
                      OVER ( PARTITION BY table_schema, table_name, constraint_name ORDER BY row_num ) AS ordinal_position,
                      table_schema,
                      table_name,
                      column_name,
                      constraint_name
               FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS row_num,
                            table_schema,
                            table_name,
                            column_name,
                            constraint_name
                     FROM information_schema.constraint_column_usage) t) AS ccu
              ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name AND ccu.table_schema = tc.table_schema AND
                 ccu.ordinal_position = kcu.ordinal_position
WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
  AND tc.table_schema = 'public'
  AND tc.table_name = 'xxx';

I've used EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) and basically the optimiser is just going off at a tangent, and the tipping point seems to be 95+ tables in the schema.  I haven't put the EXPLAIN in this thread as they are quite long, but anyone can try this on any Postgres database, it's just querying the data model schema. I wonder if some trick exists to direct the use of one optimisation over the other without changing the SQL, as it's part of an open source library so I'm not sure of the exact intent of the query?
Here is the tail of the EXPLAIN in both cases on the same laptop, same schema,, just different number of tables defined:
THE GOOD
->  Index Only Scan using pg_namespace_oid_index on pg_namespace nc_3  (cost=0.13..0.18 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
Index Cond: (oid = c_3.connamespace)
Heap Fetches: 1
Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=779 read=64
Planning Time: 9.951 ms
Execution Time: 7.677 ms

THE BAD
->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute a  (cost=0.29..0.46 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((attrelid = r_2.oid) AND (attnum = ((information_schema._pg_expandarray(c_2.conkey))).x))
"        Filter: ((NOT attisdropped) AND (pg_has_role(r_2.relowner, 'USAGE'::text) OR has_column_privilege(r_2.oid, attnum, 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REFERENCES'::text)))"
Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=118
Planning Time: 10.022 ms
Execution Time: 1254.787 ms

I've tried to reindex database and upping the cache sizes but nothing brings the fast optimisation back.

Please replace the explanation why you didn't provide query plans with actual query plans. If those are entirely too long, post to explain.depesz.com or explain.dalibo.com and provide the links.

Hi @ErwinBrandstetter, Thanks for all the feedback, and the links, no idea they existed.  I don't know why the SQL is so convoluted without opening up the open source code, which I haven't yet done, I also don't know if the SQL is built up or just neat.
link and link.  Certainly forcing sorts is never good, but this is such a tiny DB it shouldn't matter.

After bad row estimates, some nested loops in your query plan totally spiral out of control. All in all: Buffers: shared hit=633580 ... Even your "fast" query uses Buffers: shared hit=1,369. My equivalent query (see query plan in my answer) only uses Buffers: shared hit=23'. A needlessly convoluted query on top of the already convoluted information schema. I don't think there is much blame left for your system. Out of curiosity: what happens to your slow query after SET enable_nestloop = off; (only in your session).

Hearing that the query "runs from an open source library", I was ready to assume it has some merit.
It doesn't. The pile of noise burns down to:
SELECT constraint_name, kcu.column_name, ccu.table_name, ccu.column_name, 0
FROM   information_schema.table_constraints tc
JOIN   information_schema.key_column_usage kcu USING (constraint_name, table_schema)
JOIN   information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu USING (constraint_name, table_schema)
WHERE  tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND    tc.table_schema = 'public'
AND    tc.table_name = 'xxx';

What's more, if you want it fast, don't involve the information schema, which is notoriously convoluted and slow. Use the system catalog instead.
Equivalent query:
SELECT c.conname AS constraint_name, a1.attname AS column_name    -- "column_name" twice?
     , confrelid::regclass AS table_name, a2.attname AS column_name  -- really?
     , 0
FROM   pg_constraint c
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a1 ON a1.attnum = ANY(c.conkey)  -- possibly mult. cols
                                 AND a1.attrelid = c.conrelid
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a2 ON a2.attnum = ANY(c.confkey)  -- possibly mult. cols
                                 AND a2.attrelid = c.confrelid
WHERE  c.contype = 'f'  -- FOREIGN KEY
AND    c.conrelid = 'public.xxx'::regclass;  -- assuming public schema

This is what I get for ~ 80 user tables in my test DB:
'Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..20.82 rows=1 width=200) (actual time=0.024..0.041 rows=2 loops=1)'
'  Buffers: shared hit=23'
'  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.55..15.12 rows=1 width=155) (actual time=0.019..0.029 rows=2 loops=1)'
'        Join Filter: (a1.attnum = ANY (c.conkey))'
'        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 32'
'        Buffers: shared hit=15'
'        ->  Index Scan using pg_constraint_conrelid_contypid_conname_index on pg_constraint c  (cost=0.27..4.46 rows=1 width=118) (actual time=0.008..0.010 rows=2 loops=1)'
'              Index Cond: (conrelid = ''19409''::oid)'
'              Filter: (contype = ''f''::"char")'
'              Rows Removed by Filter: 1'
'              Buffers: shared hit=5'
'        ->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute a1  (cost=0.28..10.28 rows=17 width=70) (actual time=0.002..0.006 rows=17 loops=2)'
'              Index Cond: (attrelid = ''19409''::oid)'
'              Buffers: shared hit=10'
'  ->  Index Scan using pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index on pg_attribute a2  (cost=0.28..5.69 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=2)'
'        Index Cond: (attrelid = c.confrelid)'
'        Filter: (attnum = ANY (c.confkey))'
'        Rows Removed by Filter: 7'
'        Buffers: shared hit=8'
'Planning:'
'  Buffers: shared hit=3'
'Planning Time: 0.199 ms'
'Execution Time: 0.067 ms'

And it won't get much slower, even for thousands of tables.
Related:

information_schema vs. system catalogs
Delete rows with foreign key in PostgreSQL
How to check if a table exists in a given schema


Still, even your odd query should shouldn't ever take a second. The usual housekeeping can help to prevent a bad query plan:

REINDEX SYSTEM
appropriate cost settings, especially for random_page_cost, work_mem, shared_buffers and effective_cache_size

We would have to study your actual execution plan to find specific problems in your setup.

I had already reindexed the system and upped all the settings you mention except random page cost,  I'll look at that. Thanks.
